# Jquery validate submitHandler called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am using unobtrusive-validation to validate my jQuery form. When form is submitted, i need to call my custom function before posting my form. Here i used submit handler which serves my need.

But the function code called multiple times.

Please find my code from below;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {

      var validator = $("#myForm").data('validator');    
      validator.settings.submitHandler = function (form) {
      var target = $(form).attr('onvalidated');
       window[target]();
           if (typeof window[target] === 'function') {
                formok = window[target]();
                form.submit();
                }
            };
    });

    function MyFunction()
    {
    alert('called');
    }

  </script>
    <style>
        .field-validation-error {
            color: red;
        }

        .input-validation-error {
        border: 1px solid red !important;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="action_page.php" id="myForm" onvalidated="MyFunction">
      First name:<br>
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="fname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" data-val-required="First name is required" data-val="true" />

      <br>
      Last name:<br>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="lname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" data-val-required="Last name is required" data-val="true" />

      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here alert got 2 times. please help to solve.

I need to call only one time after all validation passed or just before posting.

Comment: Remove the first `window[target]();` it's redundant.

Comment: The way you attached submit handler to the form is really wierd... Why not use jQuery's way while you're already using it? like this

`$('#myForm').submit(function () {  ... you codes here ... });`

also, I can see that you calling your 'target' which is your `MyFunction` twice in your codes, that explains 2 alerts...

Comment: @Mr.DucNguyen yes i just show my demo code here. In original i used submit function only and i used before send option of ajax to call my custom function. I used validator settings to enable hidden field validation and my custom styles

Comment: is it working after removing window[target](); ?

Comment: yes its working thanks. @Novice please give as answer